# how to GRANT some user managing row in some table WHERE (condition)

Tags: sql, mysql

i am dealing with several tables connected to one named "servers". there are ids and names of servers. i need to somehow GRANT *one_of_these_servers*_admin deleting inserting and all regular admin's permisions for all table BUT *one_of_these_servers*_admin can do this only if rows in the table connected with *one_of_these_servers*

is it looks like:

```
CREATE USER 'server_admin' IDENTIFIED BY 'qwerty123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* WHERE servers.`name` = 'one_of_these_servers' TO 'server_admin';
```

or i can do it only with views and procedures?